# Android scale background image in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, scale, drawable

How do I scale the background image in my LinearLayout?
My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewJuli01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    ....

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The background image is pretty much distorted. How to solve this issue?

Comment: firstly try to change the image with proper quality as you required.

Comment: Use the proper density buckets.

Comment: what excatly do you mean?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I did that still does not work